# Div with fixed header, content scrollable while hovered over header

Tags: html, css, vue.js, sass

I have a scrollable content div with a fixed header on the top. The issue is when the user is hovering over the header and tries to scroll, the content doesn't scroll. How can I keep the header fixed to the top while being able to scroll the content on header hover?

```css
body {
        margin: 0;
    }
    .wrapper {
        width: 60%;
    }
    .header {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: calc(60% - 2em);
        padding: 1em;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: #e5e5e5;
    }
    .content {
        max-height: 300px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        padding-top: 3.5em;
    }
    a.tile {
        width: calc(33.333% - 32px);
        height: 200px;
        margin-bottom: 6px;
        padding: 12px;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 12px;
        border: 1px solid #efefef;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <span>9 of 25</span>
            <div class="links">
                <a href="#" disabled>Previous</a>
                <a href="#">Next</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <a href="#" class="tile">Tile 1</a>
            <a href="#" class="tile">Tile 2</a>
            <a href="#" class="tile">Tile 3</a>
            <a href="#" class="tile">Tile 4</a>
            <a href="#" class="tile">Tile 5</a>
            <a href="#" class="tile">Tile 6</a>
            <a href="#" class="tile">Tile 7</a>
            <a href="#" class="tile">Tile 8</a>
            <a href="#" class="tile">Tile 9</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

You can see in the example the body will scroll when hovered over the header, but not the content div. Issue is seen better in full screen view.

Comment: You can set `pointer-events: none` on the header, and all its descendants to `pointer-events: auto`.

Comment: @Terry I do like that solution, any ideas on how to prevent the cursor from being pointer when there's a link underneath?

Comment: The main issue is that header is not part of the element that overflows. Is there anything that stops you from using position sticky? Is the DOM fixed in a way that cannot be changed?

Comment: @Terry My actual project is a complex, highly nested Vue project, but you're right, if I can move the header into the scrollable area element it will fix the issue. I think that's my solution, great catch and thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why scrolling when the cursor is over the header doesn't work is because the header element is not a child of the scrollable element: therefore scroll events will not work.

If you are allowed to change the DOM, I'd suggest moving the header into the overflowing container instead: then scroll events are handled automatically. Moreover, using `position: sticky` on it will ensure the browser reserves sufficient space for the element, without you needing to define a top padding: see proof-of-concept below:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 60%;
}

.header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.content {
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

a.tile {
  width: calc(33.333% - 32px);
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  padding: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="header">
        <span>9 of 25</span>
        <div class="links">
          <a href="#" disabled>Previous</a>
          <a href="#">Next</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="tile">Tile 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="tile">Tile 2</a>
      <a href="#" class="tile">Tile 3</a>
      <a href="#" class="tile">Tile 4</a>
      <a href="#" class="tile">Tile 5</a>
      <a href="#" class="tile">Tile 6</a>
      <a href="#" class="tile">Tile 7</a>
      <a href="#" class="tile">Tile 8</a>
      <a href="#" class="tile">Tile 9</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```